# Questions on file structure of full stack apps for deployment

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, web-deployment, mern

I'm pretty new to developing and deploying full stack applications, so I had a few questions that I've been having a hard time finding the answer to.

I have 2 projects currently. An Express/NodeJS Backend project that contains my API (generated with express-generator), running on port 9000, which I run with npm start.
Its file structure is like this:

[image]

Then, I have a separate React project for my front-end (generated with create-react-app), running on port 3000, which I run with npm start.

Its file structure is like so:

[image]

When I go to deploy this, whether it be on Heroku or AWS or whatever, it needs to be one consolidated project that contains both the front-end and back-end projects, correct? I have seen project layouts that are basically a React app + 1 File for backend, like so:

[image]

1. To deploy my two apps (React App and Express API) as a website, do I need them to be one single project?
2. If Yes to 1, then why do people use create-react-app and express-generator if it ultimately doesn't leave you with a file-structure for a fullstack app?
3. Is there any guide that shows how to combine (in the literal sense of file structure, since the two apps are already communicating fine) two apps created with express generator and create-react-app?
4. If I need to combine them, what does this mean for my package.json?

Right now, in my backend package.json, I have the scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

and in my front end package.json, I have the scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

I'd imagine that if the two projects are to be merged, the start script would need to be altered to run both?

Interested in learning best practices for the file structure of a fullstack application (In this case, MERN stack just without Mongo). Any advice or suggestions are really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You don't need React and Express projects to be a single project. In development mode you start two projects separately. In production you need to build React app and put it to the `public` directory of the Express project. The Express will contain your React project as a set of static files.

Comment: @KenBekov Oh I really hadn't thought of that. So what you're saying is, even if I have two separate projects for development, I would only need to deploy the express app, and it would have a static set (a build) of my front-end to serve with it? Is there any specific tool I'm supposed to use to put my client's build into the express app, or would I just run npm run build and then copy the dist folder into the express app under bin or something? Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: you can build and copy React app manually. If you use any continues integration tool like Jenkins, you can set up the tool to  build and deploy your application automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> To deploy my two apps (React App and Express API) as a website, do I need them to be one single project?

No. You can even deploy them to different domains and treat the frontend as another product. There are [pros and cons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194822/when-to-separate-a-project-in-multiple-subprojects) in keeping both apps in the same Git repository.

> If Yes to 1, then why do people use create-react-app and
> express-generator if it ultimately doesn't leave you with a
> file-structure for a fullstack app?

People use CRA because it's the default way by Facebook and simply works. But many people do Server Side Rendering using frameworks like [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/) or another boilerplate.

> Is there any guide that shows how to combine (in the literal sense of
> file structure, since the two apps are already communicating fine) two
> apps created with express generator and create-react-app?

If you are simply communicating via API, keep both in different folders.

For React, you are gonna create an optimized [production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) anyway (you don't need node constantly running in your server to serve the final html and Javascript files).

For the backend, even if you use another language, you deploy normally, as you would while using static html.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was very informative. I think I'll try to deploy them both separately and have them communicate on separate domains. To be clear, if I host the backend on AWS on some ec2 server, and then use a separate one for my front-end (and do the necessary steps to mask the aws url with my custom domain name), my front end would still be able to make requests to backend-ec2-instance.aws.com from myDomain.com? In my express app I have the line "app.use(cors());". Is that what will allow those cross-domain requests? Thanks again.

Comment: While you can use different domains, it's up to you and your needs. In my app, for instance, I reserve `domain.com/api/...` for all APIs (handled by php). All remaining routes `domain.com/foo...` are handled by react-router, possibly resulting in a 404 error page. The `php`, `build` and `public` folders are at the same server.